Some questions about integration and operator theory.
As we all know there are multiple integral operators which all basically do the same thing in various contexts. I am talking about operators like the Lebegues integral, Riemann integral and more generally things like the Kolomogrov integral and Henstock-Kurzweil integral. Thinking and reading up on these while having some ideas of diffeology in mind led to a bit of introspection.

I was wondering about the behaviors of a space of functions that were {p} integrable, {p} being some family of integrals that are defined on partitions of opens in R or R^n or even more general spaces. What would some example spaces be say if we had the lebegues integral of two different measures or a family of measures. Or say the behaviors of functions both narrow and wide Denjoy integrable.
The possible "extension" of the ideas behind diffeology to a family of plots that would represent our different integrations. Finding good families of integrals to play with (ways of generating different integrals) and generally developping some axioms to go along with it. Since integration seems to have some of that sheaf like/pseudo-group like structure. (Locality and Covering are the ones I managed to show: Locality: suppose a function is integrable over all bits of a partition then its integrable over the partition (with some caveats on choice of integration and type of functions).
Covering: The integral of a family of integrable functions is a family of integrable functions and if the right integral is chosen the integration is covering. (0 generates constant functions and their sums generate the whole space). )
If it is possible to construct a sort of Riemann Sum of integrals (as operation applied to f) for a function defined on an interval where a family {p} of integrals converge. Said otherwise have some sort of integral of integrals in a way to integrate a function over a directed partition of its domain (lets say E) by doing something like taking the limit as the partition size approaches infinity of $\sum_{p \in \{p\}}\sum_{e \in E} f\delta p_e$ where we sum at every e the values of the different p in {p}.

I am an undergraduate so any book recommendations and advice/knowledge is very welcome. I would like to apologize for the fuzzy nature of the question for I am put of my depth here. Are there any books going into detail about how people build integrals and how the different kinds of integrals are used?

What is diffeology? As a suggestion, I would try to think of a concrete question you have in mind because the lack of focus in the question, along with a lack of clarity of what it is you are asking, may lead to the question eventually being closed. Are you interested in functions which are integrable in the Riemann and Lebesgue sense simultaneously? Are you asking about axioms of integration that lead to one of the common senses of integration (e.g. Riemann)? I have to admit I cannot parse your third question at all.

Diffeology is a very recent (my math years) development in differential geometry that was introduced to me by a teacher. It is a generalisation of manifolds and smoothness. In concrete terms a diffeology is a subspace of parametrisations from open subsets of R^n for n in N s.t the plots in the subspace satisfy certain sheaf like properties. Those of locality, covering and compatibility. In short think the usual axioms for a atlas in a smooth manifold but without the requirements for the plots making that up being a homeomorphism ( or bijections) and without any topology on M.

More generally I am looking to see if there is a way to define an atlas using integration. And if there is a way to make interesting spaces with the integral operator. The third question is a slightly more far fetched idea that comes from the definition of an average. On a continuous context the average can be made into the riemann sum of a function but what if I took values of different integrals instead to make up this sum. I was inspired by the Kolomogrov integral on this one and would appreciate any sources on it.
